# Can I run an Azure Function which needs to run more as 1 hour?

Tags: powershell, timer, azure-functions, timeout

Can I run an scheduled ps Azure Function which needs to run more as 1 hour? I already try consumption and premium plan, but the scheduled Azure function stuck because of a timeout.

**Update**

I try to get all the group members in AAD. I run this ms graph url:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$top=999&$expand=members

But because there are more as 999 groupmembers I need to use the paging functionality. See code snippet below:

```
$allPages = @()
    $items = (Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Get' -Uri 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups?$top=999&$expand=members' -Headers $authHeader  -ContentType 'Application/Json') 
    $allPages += $items.value

    $index = 0
    if ($items.'@odata.nextLink') {
            do {
                  $index++
                  "Index counter: $index"

                  $token = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl "https://graph.microsoft.com/").Token
                  $authHeader = @{Authorization = "Bearer $token"}

                  $items = (Invoke-RestMethod -Method 'Get' -Uri $items.'@odata.nextLink' -Headers $authHeader  -ContentType 'Application/Json')
                  $allPages += $items.value
             } until (
                 !$items.'@odata.nextLink'
             )
    }

    $items = $allPages
    "Count items: " + $items.Count

    $filePath = "D:\home\data\$($fileName)"

    Write-Host "Convert to csv to path '$($filePath)'" -ForegroundColor green
    $items | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $filePath
```

Comment: This question needs a few more details if you need help debugging or identifying a workaround. How did you configure the timeout after upgrading hosting plans? Are there any error messages associated with the timeout? Does the function depend on other remote services or APIs? Do you know why it takes >1 hour to run in the first place, and is that expected?

Comment: @KEM, try using **App Service plan** as it allows **unbounded execution** , you can set the function timeout to more than one hour. Refer [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#functiontimeout).

Comment: mathias , @ravallika, I updated my post. I try to get all the group members in my tenant and export to csv. I dont get an error, but it just stuck when I do a test run. I dont see the session in log history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can I run an Azure Function which needs to run more as 1 hour?

yes, you can run the Azure functions more than one hour.

- In **Consumption Plan**, default duration is *5minutes* and Maximum duration is *10 minutes*.
- In **Premium Plan**, default duration is *30 minutes*. Though *maximum duration* is technically unbounded, function execution is guaranteed only for *60minutes*.
- So, you can go with **Dedicated(App Service)** plan which allows to *increase the timeout for more than an hour*.

Set the **functionTimeout** attribute in `host.json`:

```json
{
  "functionTimeout":"02:00:00"
}
```

- created a PowerShell Azure function and using `functionTimeout` attribute to set the timeout of the function.

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "managedDependency": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  },
  "functionTimeout":"02:00:00"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]